# Does it make sense to create seperate data application layers that interact in asp.net mvc?

Tags: mvc, layers

I work with csv files that after some steps provide the initial data, and with a database that is derived from this data. The database then is read from and written to in many different ways by the rest of the application, the csv files are then ignored.

Therefore the idea arose to make one data application layer for working with the csv files, which only happens before any user input or queries are made. And to make a separate data application layer for the database, which is constantly used whilst the application runs.

These data application layers only need to interact once and in one direction, from the eventual csv files to the database. Would it be more sensible to do it all in one data application layer or is this a matter of taste?

Comment: It makes sense in terms of separation of concerns. How you structure and/or deploy that is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all the csv files are for is seeding the database initially, correct?  If that's the case, I would include it in the same data application layer since access to those CSV files wouldn't be needed anywhere else.

Comment: The csv files as they are initially provided are not the ones that eventually make the database though, there are several actions needed to create new csv files out of them, the data of which then fills the eventual database

Comment: @Miles: I'm not sure how your response contradicts what this answer tries to confirm. The CSV files represent the initial data state from which the database is created (regardless of whether there's an additional inbetween step at the time of actually seeding the database), correct?